# Yocto build fail with exit code '134'

Tags: yocto, wsl-2

I am trying to yocto build on wsl2 and face these kinds of errors whenever I try to build.

```
ERROR: Task (/home/minwoo/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '134'
ERROR: Task (/home/minwoo/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/update-rc.d/update-rc.d_0.8.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '134'
```

I attached more build log lines here.
What is 134 error and How can I resolve it?

```
➜  rpi-build bitbake core-image-minimal
WARNING: You are running bitbake under WSLv2, this works properly but you should optimize your VHDX file eventually to avoid running out of storage space
Loading cache: 100% |                                                                                                                                 | ETA:  --:--:--
Loaded 0 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:06
Parsing of 806 .bb files complete (0 cached, 806 parsed). 1410 targets, 42 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.49.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-18.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.2+snapshot-796be0593a607938aef3941372a9238b7e895446"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp       = "master:796be0593a607938aef3941372a9238b7e895446"

NOTE: Fetching uninative binary shim http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/uninative/2.9/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.xz;sha256sum=d07916b95c419c81541a19c8ef0ed8cbd78ae18437ff28a4c8a60ef40518e423 (will check PREMIRRORS first)
Initialising tasks: 100% |#############################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 1093 Found 0 Missed 1093 Current 0 (0% match, 0% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: Task (/home/minwoo/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '134'
ERROR: Task (/home/minwoo/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/update-rc.d/update-rc.d_0.8.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '134'
Waiting for 1 running tasks to finish:
0: linux-yocto-5.8.18+gitAUTOINC+7883b60d32_3c5d210805-r0 do_fetch (pid 20443)  28% |####################                                                    | 1.99M/s
```

Comment: @Mino Have you solved the problem?

Comment: For anybody who is stumbeling upon this, it might be a bug with pseudo in the gatesgarth branch. See https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14175

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@hellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021920/hellow) pointed a workaround is part of the bug report.

Adding the folllowing line to local.conf fixed this.

```
PSEUDO_IGNORE_PATHS_append = ",/run/"
```

About your first question what is 134 error.
Bitbake is actually runs other programs in order to compile, install, patch and so forth its recipes. One of this programs is pseudo which is a fakeroot like program the first call to pseudo exits with code 134 which means it was aborted with with the SIGABRT signal because pseudo could not setup its environment.

Answer (score 5):

This problem generally goes away after cleanall operation the recipe:

> bitbake <recipe-name> -c cleanall

In your case, you need to execute above command for two recipes (initscripts & update-rc.d).

Here is an explanation for this issue: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Pseudo_Abort